# Compare two dataframes to find missing values within a range

Tags: r, compare, dataframe

I have the following 2 data.frames:

```
a1 <- data.frame(count = 1:10, site = "a")
a2 <-data.frame(count = 2:8, site = "b")
a4 <- data.frame(count = c(3,6,7,9), site = "a")
a5 <- data.frame(count = c(3,5,7), site = "b")
data1 <- rbind(a1, a2)
data2 <- rbind(a4, a5)
```

I want to generate a dataframe listing the rows in data1 that are not found in data2 based on the column "count". There are many ways to do this such as:

```
method1 <- rbind(data1, data2)
method1[!duplicated(method1,fromLast = FALSE)&!duplicated(method1,fromLast = TRUE),]
```

Which returns:

```
   count site
1      1    a
2      2    a
4      4    a
5      5    a
8      8    a
10    10    a
11     2    b
13     4    b
15     6    b
17     8    b
```

Or something like this (as a side question, this line of code isn't working perfectly and I would appreciate any insight because I have been using this command in several other data processing steps):

```
method2 <- data1[!data1$count %in% data2$count,]
```

Anyways, the main question is: How can I return the missing rows **only** within the range of counts in data2? I.e., I want the output to be:

```
   count site
4      4    a
5      5    a
8      8    a
13     4    b
15     6    b
```

I have hundreds of dataframes, each containing many sites with highly variable ranges.

This is my first time posting, thanks for taking the time to read my question and I appreciate any suggested solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think his does what you want "listing the rows in data1 that are not found in data2 based on the column "count":

```
method2 <- data1[!data1$count %in% data2$count,]
result <- subset(method2, method2$count > min(data2$count) & 
                 method2$count < max(data2$count))
```

Your code

```
method2 <- data1[!data1$count %in% data2$count,]
```

does what it is supposed to do, but it seems like that you not only want to exclude variables based on `count` but based on a combination of `count` and `site`...?

EDIT: OK, so it seems that you do want to take into account site as well, and not just count. In this case, is this what you want?

```
method2 <- data1[! interaction(data1$count, data1$site) %in%
                     interaction(data2$count,data2$site),]
result <- subset(method2, method2$count > min(data2$count) & 
               method2$count < max(data2$count))
```

EDIT2: Now the values are within the range defined by each site.

```
method2[apply(method2, 1, function(x)  
                 as.numeric(x["count"]) > min(data2$count[data2$site == x["site"]]) &
                 as.numeric(x["count"]) < max(data2$count[data2$site == x["site"]]) )
        ,]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is close, but method2 isn't returning 5 for site A or 6 for site B. And the subset range needs to be specific for each site (site A ranges from 3-9 and site B ranges from 3-7). So perhaps I need some sort of apply function that gets the range specifically for each site?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it again! Method2 looks great. The only issue with result is that it looks at the range of "count" across all data2. I want the subset range to be specific to each site as well. Would interaction work here as well?

Comment: Works great! Thanks for taking the time to refine the answer (and the question!)

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like:

```
data1[ setdiff(data1$count, data2$count),]
```

Doesn't this give the rows in data1 that are not in data2?

Comment: not really, especially if the count variable is not in order. Moreover, this solution would not give rows 11, 13 and 17 from data1, that also meet the criteria that their `count` values are not found in `data2$count`